# Angular Select dropdown set selected value

Tags: angularjs, dropdown

```
<select ng-if="PF_Set.PF.length > 0">
   <option ng-if="PF_Set.showPleaseSelect && PF_Set.PF.length>1">Please Select</option>
   <option ng-repeat="PF in PF_Set.PF" ng-click="doSomething()">{{::PF.SelectedDisplayValue}}</option>
</select>
```

The list has values like SelectedDisplayValue and isSelected.  Only one item in the list will have isSelected=true.  Can I have this as the selected value in the dropdown?

**Updated - still with issues**

```
<select ng-model="PF_set.PF" ng-attr-id="{{item.Index + '_' + PF_set.Type}}" ng-if="PF_set.PF.length > 0 >                                                                       
   <option ng-selected="PF.isSelected" ng-repeat="PF in PF_set.PF">{{PF.isSelected}} : {{::PF.SelectedDisplayValue}}</option>
</select>
```

**Updated - 1 minor issue remaining, need to add "please select" to top of list if none selected**

removed the ng-model.  This must have caused a lot of confusion with the ng-repeat

```
<select ng-attr-id="{{item.Index + '_' + PF_set.Type}}" ng-if="PF_set.PF.length > 0 >                                                                       
   <option ng-selected="PF.isSelected" ng-repeat="PF in PF_set.PF">{{PF.isSelected}} : {{::PF.SelectedDisplayValue}}</option>
</select>
```

Comment: looks like angularjs to me, please check your question tag, currently you have tagged angular, which refers to Angular 2+

Answer (score 1):

You can use `ng-selected` directive:
[example](http://jsfiddle.net/gudzdanil/ADukg/14738/)

```
<option ng-repeat="PF in PF_Set.PF" 
  ng-selected="PF.isSelected">
{{PF.SelectedDisplayValue}}
</option>
```

Comment: I'm having issues with my code - I've updated the question
1) What I see is that my first value is blank, whereas yours has a value.
2) The isSelected only seems to work in the first dropdown.  The other ones are coming up as blank.
3) When I select a value I get an error: "Error: [ngRepeat:dupes] Duplicates in a repeater are not allowed."

Comment: I added ng-model on the select.  When I removed it I fixed issues.  I now have to add a "please select" value to the top of the list if none are selected.